# Vb.Net RDLC sum field with same field's previous values

Tags: vb.net, rdlc, vb.net-2010

To the point, I created a report using Report Wizard on Visual Studio 2010 Vb.Net.
The layout is pretty much like this :

```
          DEBIT               CREDIT               BALANCE (FYI, this is an Expression)
      -----------------------------------------------------------------
         DValue1              CValue1           DValue1-CValue1 
         DValue2              CValue2           DValue2-CValue2+DValue1-CValue1
         etc...
      -----------------------------------------------------------------
Total    DTotal               CTotal
```

I managed to create up to the DTotal and CTotal, what problematic is when I want to create the Balance with Expression.

I tried this Expression, still no good.
    `=Sum(Fields!Debet.Value)-Sum(Fields!Credit.Value)+Previous(Fields!Debet)-Previous(Fields!Debet)`.
This Expression returns an error that I should not use an aggregate within another aggregate.

Please help me with this. There aren't many rdlc related tutorial even on google.

Thank you so much.

Comment: you might want to search SSRS instead of RDLC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but I believe you're looking for the [`RunningValue` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251660%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
=RunningValue(Fields!Debet.Value,Sum,"MyGroupName") - RunningValue(Fields!Credit.Value,Sum,"MyGroupName")
```

Comment: RunningValue it is! Thanks a lot, friend! Been struggling about this for a while!

Comment: Just updating, I used Nothing as GroupName. So it's like this : `=RunningValue(Fields!Debet.Value,Sum,Nothing) - RunningValue(Fields!Credit.Value,Sum,Nothing)` . Hope it helps others.